# Is it possible to have position sticky behaviour confined to specific grid rows?

Tags: css, css-position, css-grid, sticky

I have a basic 2-column layout: One for an image, one for text. Since the text column can potentially become quite long I'd like the image to scroll along. I can achieve that easily enough with `position: sticky;`, but at the end there is a third container spanning both columns. Since all three elements are in the same grid, the image with `position: sticky;` overlaps the third container.

Is there way to confine the image to the first grid row, without using JS or adding additional containers?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/y27unz9L/
`.element-1` is the one I want to confine to the first grid row.

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="element-1"></div>
  <div class="element-2"></div>
  <div class="element-3"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2em;
  align-items: start;
}

.element-1 {
  min-height: 10vh;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  position: sticky;
  top: 1em;
  background: red;
}

.element-2 {
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  background: blue;
}

.element-3 {
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2em;
  align-items: start;
}

.element-1 {
  min-height: 10vh;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  position: sticky;
  top: 1em;
  background: red;
}

.element-2 {
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  background: blue;
}

.element-3 {
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background: yellow;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="element-1"></div>
  <div class="element-2"></div>
  <div class="element-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Answers which explain the changes made to code and the reasons for those changes are generally down voted less often than those which only show code.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm I would have element-1 to be the cell and stick something inside it. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/7pcr8fvz/.

```
<div class="element-1">
  <div class='sticky'>
  </div>
</div>

.element-1 {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  align-self: stretch; //so it's 100% of the available height
}
.element-1 .sticky {
  position: sticky; //make this element sticky
  top: 1em;
  background: red;
  height: 10vh;
}
```

The problem with making `.element-1` sticky is that it's relative to the grid, if you make a child sticky the child is positioned relative to `.element-1`.